# Worksheet_SelectionChange not firing on subsequent click/change of same cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am using `Worksheet_SelectionChange()` in a sheet with multiple input fields. It works as expected (fires every time) if a user only modifies a field once, or if a user modifies, say, field/range A1 then B1 then A1 again. (Worksheet_SelectionChange fires all 3 times).

However, if user modifies A1 then A1 again subsequently after, `Worksheet_SelectionChange()` does not fire.

Is there another method that will "see" a change in the cell that is changed more than once in a row?

Comment: If you are monitoring changes to cells why not use the Worksheet_Change event?

Comment: `Worksheet_SelectionChange` doesn't have anything to do with whether a cell is *modified*.  The `Worksheet_Change` event does that.

Comment: To distinguish between the two, `SelectionChange` fires every time a different cells is selected. `Change` fires anytime a change is made to any cell.

Comment: OK, you guys are all pointing in the same direction and that makes sense. So I am misusing Worksheet_SelectionChange and should be checking for value changes in Worksheet_Change instead. I will accept that answer if someone wants to post it.